# Javascript: does it save memory to define large objects inside functions that are called only when needed?

Tags: javascript, memory

On a certain page of my web app, I need to define several quite large objects (over 1000 lines of code each). Right now their definition code is on the main thread, like:

```
var Library = {};

Library.objectA = { /* ... 1000s of lines ... */ };
Library.objectB = { /* ... 1000s of lines ... */ };
Library.objectC = { /* ... 1000s of lines ... */ };
```

However, I only need these objects sometimes, depending on user actions. I'm wondering if it will be less taxing to the browser's memory if I handle things more like this:

```
var Library = {};

Library.defineObjectA = function() {
    Library.objectA = { /* ... 1000s of lines ... */ };
};

document.getElementById('buttonA').addEventListener('click', function() {
    Library.defineObjectA();
    // now do something with Library.objectA
});
```

The lines of code are roughly equal - what I don't know is if the second approach will somehow save memory by only running the code to define `objectA` when needed. Any advice on this?

Comment: It should be, but saving the user a few MB of memory at most doesn't seem like much of a concern unless you are using this pattern a lot of times.

Comment: @BShaps I do use the pattern often, and it's likely for any particular object to not be used on a particular page visit. I'm not sure of the memory though, because even though `Library.objectA` is off the main thread, `Library.defineObjectA` is still there, and I'm not sure how it's memory usage would compare if not invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say I will only initialize the Objects only when user needs it, then obviously there is memory saving advantage. Sometimes user may not need the Object, then the Object will not be initialized at all, Memory is saved.

But you have to be careful though, as initializing the Object from a button click will initialize the Object every time user clicks the button because of the following script.

```
document.getElementById('buttonA').addEventListener('click', function() {
    Library.defineObjectA();
    // now do something with Library.objectA
});
```

What you need to do is, check if the Object has been already initialized when user clicks on the button, if not then initialize it.

```
document.getElementById('buttonA').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(!Library.objectA) Library.defineObjectA();
    // now do something with Library.objectA
});
```

> Does `Library.defineObjectA` method takes up more memory than `Library.objectA` Object?

When a page is loaded browser initializes the global objects starts to compile (and run) all scripts to bytecodes. Scripts when run allocates memory for variables and objects and the size of `window` object grows.

When the following script is run bytecode of the object is generated and executed and `objectA` is initialized in memory.

```
Library.objectA = { /* ... 1000s of lines ... */ };
```

When the following script is run bytecode of the function (including everything inside) is generated and a pointer to the bytecode is added to `Library` Object. No object is initialized.

```
Library.defineObjectA = function() {
    Library.objectA = { /* ... 1000s of lines ... */ };
};
```

Afterwards when the `defineObjectA` method is called `objectA` is initialized in memory and a scope memory is also allocated by the function. The scope memory holds all the local variables initialized inside the function and will not be freed after the function returns if `objectA` has any closure function (which is most likely to happen ;)

In this case we have no variables initialized inside the function, so we can neglect the scope memory and the bytecode memory of the function, so the approach of initializing the object later does save memory if not initialized by user. Though it is not tangible amount of saving but surely a good practice.

Comment: Are you certain having the function `Library.defineObjectA` defined (but not invoked) is superior to having a large `Library.objectA` defined? This is where I'm uncertain - I don't know if the defining function may require the same or more space than the object, even when uninvoked.

Comment: That's a good question. And yes I am certain of that. Until the object  is initialized the object and function will remain as **compiled code** (no memory is occupied) and little memory for the function (until invoked). Initializing the Object will create the Object in the memory along with all it's enumerable and non-enumerable properties. It's a huge difference if the Object is huge. I will improve the answer with references later.

Answer (score 0):

It saves memory at the expense of runtime speed, but it is most likely negligible.